# url is not intercepted during curl call inside bash script called by jenkins pipeline

Tags: bash, curl, jenkins-pipeline

Team,
I have no clue why am i not getting the url shown as shown in logs. if we see below url is being echoed well but during curl call it is not getting picked in jenkins logs. is my syntax or quotes not right? am trying several combinations but no luck.

script that is called by jenkins

```
    sq_url='https://product.team.com/api/quality'
    url="${sq_url}=${GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER}-${GERRIT_PATCHSET_NUMBER}"
    echo $url
    echo "1"
    echo "curl -u '${Main_TOKEN}': '${url}'"
```

```
https://product.team.com/api/quality?=89595-23
1
curl -u ****
```

Comment: You are not executing `curl`, you are only echoing a string which contains curl

Comment: The use of redacted credentials is probably obscuring the stdout.

Comment: that is right. when i enabled curl it did make a call to server. shalli  close question?

Comment: What do you mean "when I enabled curl"? But if the question is not reproducible or was caused by a typo, then yes, it should be closed/deleted

Comment: I mean you suggestion that url is hidden due to stdout being obscured. because I make a curl call using `$url` and it went through so it is just not getting printed in output.